# I am getting an Error: "The size of tensor a (10) must match the size of tensor b (64) at non-singleton dimension 1 in pytorch." in classification

Tags: pytorch, classification, perceptron

I am doing a basic classification task using single perceptron in pytorch.But getting the error message as follows:-

> UserWarning: Implicit dimension choice for softmax has been
> deprecated. Change the call to include dim=X as an argument.
> x=F.softmax(x)#Softmax non-linearity  UserWarning: Using a target size
> (torch.Size([64])) that is different to the input size
> (torch.Size([64, 10])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due
> to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.   return
> F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)

also "RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (10) must match the size of tensor b (64) at non-singleton dimension 1
"
Code is given below.Kindly help to correct this error.

```
class perceptron(nn.Module):
  def __init__ (self,n_channels):#n_channel=> length of feature vector
    super(perceptron,self).__init__ ()
    self.L = nn.Linear(n_channels,10)#mapping from input to output
  def forward(self,x):#x=> input
    x=self.L(x) # feed-forward
    x=F.softmax(x)#Softmax non-linearity
    return x
```

I used cifar10 dataset.The model is called using code below:

```
featLength = 2+5+2
model=perceptron(featLength)
criterion=nn.MSELoss()
model=train_model(model,criterion,num_epochs=20,learning_rate = 10)
```

Dataset is taken as follows:

```
#generate dataset in one hot vectors
trainLabel2 = np.zeros((50000,10))
testLabel2 = np.zeros((10000,10))
for d1 in range(trainLabel.shape[0]):
  trainLabel2[d1,trainLabel[d1]]=1
for d2 in range(testLabel.shape[0]):
  testLabel2[d2,testLabel[d2]]=1            


trainDataset     =TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(trainFeats),torch.from_numpy(trainLabel))  
testDataset =TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(testFeats),torch.from_numpy(testLabel))

#creating dataloader
trainLoader=DataLoader(trainDataset, batch_size=64, shuffle= True,num_workers=4)    
testLoader=DataLoader(testDataset, batch_size=64, shuffle= True,num_workers=4)  


use_gpu=torch.cuda.is_available()
use_gpu=False
```

The function for the train_model is as follows:

```
def train_model(model,criterion,num_epochs,learning_rate):
start = time.time()
train_loss=[]
train_acc=[]
tempLabels=[]
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    epochStartTime=time.time()
    print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch,num_epochs - 1))
    
    running_loss=0.0
    batch=0
    for data in trainLoader:
        inputs,labels=data
        if use_gpu:
       inputs,labels=Variable(inputs.float().cuda()),Variables(labels.float().cuda())

        else:
            inputs,labels=Variable(inputs.float()),Variable(labels.float())
        
                
                
            
        model.zero_grad()
        outputs=model(inputs)
        _,preds=outputs.data.max(1)
        loss=criterion(outputs,labels)
        running_loss += loss.data[0]
        if batch==0:
            totalLoss=loss
            totalPreds=preds
            tempLabels=labels.data.cpu()
            batch+=1
        else:
            totalLoss+=loss
            totalPreds=torch.cat((totalPreds,preds),0)
            tempLabels=torch.cat((tempLabels,labels.data.cpu()),0)
            batch+=1    
            
    totalLoss=totalLoss/batch
    totalLoss.backward()
    
    for f in model.parameters():
        f.data.sub_(f.grad.data * learning_rate)
        
    
    epoch_loss=running_loss/50000
    train_loss.append(epoch_loss)
    print('Epoch loss='+str(epoch_loss))
    
    tempLabels= tempLabels.numpy()
    _,totalLabels=np.where(tempLabels==1)
    epoch_accc=np.sum(np.equal(totalPreds.cpu().numpy(),np.array(totalLabels.cpu().numpy())))
    train_acc.append(epoch_acc)
    
    
    epochTimeEnd =time.time()-epochStartTime
    print('Epoch Complete in {:.0f}m {:.f}s'.format(epochTimeEnd // 60,epochTimeEnd % 60))
    print('-'*25)   
    
    fig1=plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(range(epoch+1),train_loss,'r--',label='train')
    if epoch==0:
        plt.legend(loc='upper left')
        plt.xlabel('Epochs')
        plt.ylabel('Loss')
    fig1.savefig('lossPlot.png')
    fig2=plt.figure(2)
    plt.plot(range(epoch+1),train_acc,'g--',label='train')
    if epoch==0:
        plt.legend(loc='upper left')
        plt.xlabel('Epochs')
        plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
    fig2.savefig('accPlot.png')
time_elapsed= time.time() - start
print('Training complete in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(time_elapsed //60 ,time_elapsed % 60) )
return model
```

Answer (score 0):

It is almost always you will need the dimension when you use softmax function:

```
x = F.softmax(x,dim=1) # or whatever dimension you choose.
```

Comment: Thank you. But,even after adding dim=1,getting this error              " RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (10) must match the size of tensor b (64) at non-singleton dimension 1"                                                                                                                        also " Using a target size (torch.Size([64])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([64, 10])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
  return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)"

Comment: i thing you should use dim =0;

Comment: The error repeats "RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (10) must match the size of tensor b (64) at non-singleton dimension 1
"